# Is there a way to improve the performance of webview in Electron?

Tags: electron

Before I used an iframe to load several HTML files into. It was very fast, but I could not download specific files, since an iframe doesn't run in its own process. So I changed to webview and I could download the files, but now everything is really slow. Is there a way to improve the performance of webview? Maybe by sending the links through the IPC? I have not worked with it yet and in the tutorials they just send some simple messages.